# Looking for a Tosafos

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, marriage, tosfot, maseches-kesubos

I remember seeing a Tosafos in Ksubos a while back which states that when a man gets married, he should go to his in-laws for the chag that follows his wedding. Does anyone know exactly where I can find it?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Gemara or Tosfos there, but Pesachim 8:1 is probably relevant.

Answer (score 8):

I did a quick and dirty search and came up with this quote

תוספות מסכת כתובות דף עא עמוד ב

> " פירש ר"ח דרגל ראשון היא רגילה לילך ולהגיד שבחה בבית אביה "

It is in the last Tos on the page, 5 lines up from the bottom, D"H 
כאן ברדופה כאן בשאינה רדופה

Comment: "quick and dirty"

Comment: Yes -- brute force and guesswork. No skill or finesse.